# boost::threads program causes lots of race conditions

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety, boost-thread

I have a program where I use boost::threads for multi threading. Unfortunately drd (`valgrind --tool=drd ./my_program`) reports lot of problems about 10000.

I am not sure if I misunderstood something of boost thread. I try to find out my error for hours but did not get much further, therefore any help would be appreciated.

I try to pipeline certain filters and want to be able to run them by calling the last filter with run. This filter should then first call all his precursor filter which he depend on and in the end call his processQueue() methode.
I want now to be able to call precursor filters in their won thread, so that I get a speed up if the graph as parallel paths. Therefore I added the threadgroup, so that each precursor filter is executed in his own thread. But unfortunately I get a lot of race conditions where I am not sure where they result from.
I hope now it is more clear what I want to achieve.

**Update**

I have updated the code to a even simpler code where the problem still occurs. I think the problem is somewhere related to the thread generation.

**Update 2**

I think the main reason for these is a very high false positive rate of valgrind. I have opened a new question about this. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999360/debug-boostthread-application-high-false-positive-rate)

**Update 3**

most of the errors could be avoided when I use valgrind 3.6.1 instead of 3.7.0 or 3.8.0.

Here one report of drd:

```
==29905== Conflicting load by thread 1 at 0xb0081000 size 8
==29905==    at 0x25A6C2: pthread_join (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==29905==    by 0x2BEC0: boost::thread::join() (in /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.dylib)
==29905==    by 0x100006641: Filter::run() (in ./playgroudThreads)
==29905==    by 0x100001013: main (in ./playgroudThreads)
==29905== Allocation context: unknown.
==29905== Other segment start (thread 2)
==29905==    at 0x2A7B68: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==29905== Other segment end (thread 2)
==29905==    at 0x3E667A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==29905==    by 0x3DED38: semaphore_create (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==29905==    by 0x2A50F7: new_sem_from_pool (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==29905==    by 0x2A6199: _pthread_exit (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==29905==    by 0x2A48C9: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==29905==    by 0x2A7B74: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
```

And here my example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class Filter
{
    public:

        Filter(int n) :
                n_(n), precursor_(0)
        {
        }

        ~Filter()
        {
        }

        void connect(Filter& f)
        {
            precursor_ = &f;
        }

        void run()
        {

            if (!isCalculationDone_) {
                if (precursor_) {
                    boost::thread thread(&Filter::run, precursor_);

                    thread.join();
                }
                this->processQueue(2);
                isCalculationDone_ = true;

            }

        }

        void processQueue(unsigned N)
        {
            //do some calculations

        }

    public:
        int n_;
        Filter* precursor_;

        bool isCalculationDone_;

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Filter* f1 = new Filter(1);
    Filter* f2 = new Filter(2);

    f2->connect(*f1);

    f2->run();

    std::cerr << "main: done" << std::endl;
    delete f2;
    delete f1;
    return 0;

}
;
```

Comment: could you maybe please say first what you are trying to achieve? i personally find it difficult to understand. (but then i am not so smart)

Comment: Why are you using dynamic allocation? Not only is it unnecessary, you're leaking it.

Comment: @AndersK. I have added the explanation

Comment: @GMan I use normaly boost shared_ptr, but in the minimal example I did not want to use them.

Comment: @tune2fs: Then you ought to make it truly minimal. Good C++ code is more minimal than what you have in `main`. :)

Comment: @GMan so now it is truly minimal, and without memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not alone: see the [thread](http://old.nabble.com/-drd--Race-condition-in-boost-thread-library--td28786561.html) here, which suggests the problem is a false positive "probably caused by reuse of the memory for thread-local storage from a terminated thread by a newly created thread".

Answer (score 2):

You are creating 8 Filters.  Each Filter object has its own filterMutex_ - these have nothing to do with each other.

You are creating more than 8 threads.  Is that deliberate?

Each call to `run` will launch a new thread for each precursor, calling Filter::run on that thread for that precursor Filter object.  So:

```
f8->run creates 2 threads for its precursors, calling f6->run and f7->run
 f6->run creates 2 threads: f4->run and f5->run
  f4->run creates 1 thread: f2->run
   f2->run creates 1 thread: f1->run
    f1->run creates no additional threads
  f5->run creates 1 thread: f3->run
   f3->run creates 1 thread: f1->run (different thread from the other f1->run)
    f1->run creates no additional threads
 f7->run creates 1 thread: f3->run
  f3->run creates 1 thread: f1->run
   f1->run creates no additional threads
```

So, with your 8 Filter objects, you create 10 threads (in addition to your main thread), call `f3->run` twice, and `f1->run` three times.

The multiple calls to `run` on the same object will be serialized.  Different filters are not serialized.

Not sure if any of this is causing your problem, but it's the kind of thing that makes me wonder about the design, and what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: It is supposed to create more threads than needed. If the function processQueue is called, it is checked if the result already exists and if so the function returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure what your program is actually supposed to do, but generally threading is just useful if you thread independent operations like a mathematical formula which wont need any input from any other process you want to thread, because in any other situation the thread has to wait till that other process can give those data and therefore you are risking to waste a lot of CPU time. But as such situations are unavoidable the art of threading is to implement your problem in a way in which such situations are as short and as rare as possible.

While implementing threading there is also the problem of two threads in need of one resource (like a variable) and one might perhaps change it while another thread is reading it and therefore might be provided with an inconsistent data (also your program might run completely different if one thread is faster than in other and the other way around), this is actually called a race-condition and to prevent this there are [mutexes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts) to prevent reading and writing at the same time and certain functions to let a certain thread wait for another.

My guess is that one of those two scenarios happens in your program and therefore vallgrind tells you those problems, therefore in your position I would go through your whole code and actually reconsider any dependency there is or might be between any new thread. And considering the main part:

```
f2->connect(f1);
f3->connect(f1);
f4->connect(f2);
f5->connect(f3);
f6->connect(f4);
f6->connect(f5);
f7->connect(f3);
f8->connect(f6);
f8->connect(f7);
```

and

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(filterMutex_);
```

I guess it might be the first scenario.

[This](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/drd-manual.html#drd-manual.data-races) link might help interpreting your vallgrind output. Especially the "8.2.9. Debugging OpenMP Programs" part might be interresting for you as actually quite similar output is given as an example.

[Here](http://www.quantnet.com/cplusplus-multithreading-boost/) an tutorial which seems to actually go through all those scenarios (and even a few more) and explains quite well how to use boost-threading.

Comment: As the threading starts after the generation the connect function should not cause any problems, or am I wrong?